# Un-ordered list break into new column after 3rd item

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu, where the sub items are build like this into 3 columns:

```
A D G
B E H
C F
```

*** Each letter represents an item**

How do i achieve this?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pGgR7/3/

Comment: what have you tried so far? Can you share a fiddle with the markup you've used?

Comment: Sure! It's updated now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using CSS3 `column-count` property?

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wgTut/)

> Note: Support for this property is dicey at the moment, for more info
>   on support for this property, you can refer [here](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn)